# Execute Bit For Folders But Not Files

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a folder called Movies with sub-folders called Movie1, Movie2 etc, and then the movie inside of that sub-directory. Example below:

```
 Movies:
  Movie1
     film.whatever1
  Movie2
     film.whatever1
  Movie3
     film.whatever1
  Movie4
     film.whatever1
  Movie5
     film.whatever1
```

I want the permissions to be 755 for directories so that anyone can navigate down to Movie1-5 folders (the only reason this is 755 and not 744 is because the execute bit is required to change into a directory). But I want all the film.whatever1-5 files to be read-only. I cannot for the life of me figure out if that's possible.

I tried to do this using the setfacl command with the upper case X as shown below:

```
 setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx Movies
 setfacl -R -d -m g::r-X Movies
 setfacl -R -d -m o::r-X Movies

 setfacl -R -m u::rwx Movies
 setfacl -R -m g::r-X Movies
 setfacl -R -m o::r-X Movies
```

The result was that it changed the folder and files to BOTH be executable.  It's a very annoying problem I need to solve.

Comment: AFAIK the `X` in a `setfacl` mode description (same as `chmod`) means "*execute only if the file is  a directory* **or already  has  execute  permission  for  some  user**" - it doesn't *remove* execute permission from non-directories that already have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to run different commands on regular files and directories by filtering them with the `-type` option. This runs recursively on everything inside `./Movies`:

```bsh
# all directories become 755 (rwx r-x r-x):
find ./Movies -type d -exec chmod 755 '{}' \;

# all files become 644 (rw- r-- r--):
find ./Movies -type f -exec chmod 644 '{}' \;
```